# How to call or refer to an instance attribute from another's class method

Tags: python, oop

As a Python beginner, and I'm trying to create a simple text-based game. I would like to know how to properly refer to the `monster` instance of my `Monster` class, from within the `scan` method that I defined in my `Character` class (is this is even possible?).

```
class Monster:
    def __init__(self):
        self.HP = 5
        self.color = 'blue'


class Character:
    def scan(self):
        print("{} is {} and has {} HP.".format( monster.__name__, 
                                                monster.color, 
                                                monster.HP ))


class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.monster = Monster()
        self.player = Character()

        self.player.scan()

Game()
```

I've read around a lot, trying things like `getattr`, without any luck. I know I could put my `scan` method directly in the `Game` and use `self.monster.HP` and `self.monster.color`, but I'd really like to avoid that.

Any help or criticism is welcome, thanks in advance :)

Comment: As a side note, you probably don't want `monster.__name__`. Most types don't have a `__name__` attribute—classes do, but class _instances_ don't… unless you add one. And, even if you write `Monster.__name__`, that's just going to give you the name of the class, so you'll say `Monster is blue and has 5 HP`. Presumably not all of your monsters are named `Monster`; even George Foreman named some of his kids Georgina instead of George. So, you probably want to add a `self.name` attribute to `Monster` instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd explicitly pass in the monster to scan:

```
class Character:
    def scan(self, monster):
        print("{} is {} and has {} HP.".format(
            monster.__name__, monster.color, monster.HP))
```

and:

```
self.player.scan(self.monster)
```

This way your code can also handle more than one monster.

Comment: Why do I only ever run out of votes just as I run into a Martijn Pieters answer that needs an upvote? Someone else upvote this for me. :)

Comment: Genius! I can't believe I didn't try that earlier... I looked for something waaaaay more complicated! Thanks a lot.